# jQuery.tweet.js Not working on only 1 site

Tags: javascript

I have just noticed (after not editing anything) that my twitter stream powered by Tweet! http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/ is not working one 1 site (the footer of http://josiehewitphotography.co.uk) but works on another site.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can u isolate the problem with some code. You should know that questions that are too narrow and localized are going to be closed! http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also noticed mine wasn't working anymore and now looking for an alternative.

The notice below is on http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/

> "Important note about Twitter's API changes 
>   Twitter's decision to discontinue their unauthenticated v1.0 API means that this widget will stop working at some time in 2013 -- Twitter wants your only option for on-page widgets to be their own Embedded Timelines.
>
> Please read the corresponding support issue for more information and possible current/future workarounds."

Link to the workarounds -> https://github.com/seaofclouds/tweet/issues/264

Answer (score 0):

Two parameters of the OAuth 1.0A are now mandatory:

- `oauth_callback` (must be `oauth/request_token`)
- `oauth_verifier`

Full workaround notice:

> There are two aspects to the change -- both are mandatory parts of the OAuth 1.0A spec that we've been lenient with in the past:
>
> - You must pass an oauth_callback value to oauth/request_token. It's not optional. Even if you have one already set on dev.twitter.com. If you're doing out of band OAuth, pass oauth_callback=oob.
> - You must pass along the oauth_verifier you either received from your executed callback or that you received hand-typed by your end user to oauth/access_token.